# Order by subgroup

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help building a MySQL query that will output all rows in a certain order.  The table definition contains `id`, `sub_id`, and `name`.  The `sub_id` column is used to indicate that a given row should be grouped within `id`, and if `sub_id` is blank/0/null, then the row is a top-level row.

The desired sort order is by `name`, except I want all `sub_id` rows to be grouped within their corresponding `id` row. Within each subgroup, each row should be sorted by name.

For example, given this unordered table:

```
id   sub_id   name
=====================
1    0        bananas
2    0        apples
3    0        apricots
4    2        strawberries
5    2        cherries
6    1        oranges
```

The desired order is:

```
id   sub_id   name
=====================
2    0        apples
5    2        cherries
4    2        strawberries

3    0        apricots

1    0        bananas
6    1        oranges
```

(spacing between subgroups for illustrative purposes only)

Help?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT t.id, t.sub_id, t.name
FROM table t LEFT JOIN table p on t.sub_id = p.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(p.id, t.id), t.name
```

Comment: thanks for the clever answer.  However I think this will sort by id first. So for example a row with id=1,name='xyz' and another row with id=2,name='abc' will be incorrectly sorted.  Also, I want the row with sub_id=NULL to be sorted first within the subgroup.

Comment: I suggest you set up a sqlfiddle for this http://sqlfiddle.com/ I am not sure if think it does not work, or it really does not work...